# Should I put a separation after a featured section?

Tags: website-design, footers, margin

Here is the footer of my website. A thin line with equal top/bottom margin separate content from footer.

[image: My footer]

Now if my content end by a features section, how do I separate my footer ?

[image: Solutions 1 and 2]

Comment: If you go with the Sol.1 - you should better keep that seperation border in full width, that'll look much better I think. 

Also you can increase the width of border, giving bold n thick border.

Answer (score 1):

Separators are just a method of creating a visual gap between the elements.

Technically, separators are required where there are multiple items are displayed which are at the same level in Information hierarchy. For example, a list of cards or any list where you need lines to create a visual idea of each item's boundary.

In you case, I think that background color, placement and content size is providing enough for a visual separation. Adding a bar won't hurt but it will be more of a decorative element rather than a useful one.

Lines come with its own padding (A gap between content and line itself both before and after line).

I'll assume that the line will fall dead center of the screen, the screen assets are important and I can think of many ways that space can be utilized in a better way than just adding a decorative line :)

However, if it goes really well with the overall "Design" (read look and feel) of your product than practically there is nothing wrong with putting a line as well :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is no *right* or *wrong* to this question – but instead this is actually a design decision you'll have to make:

- If the horizontal line is meant to separate the footer *from everything else* ("content") then you should go with solution1.
- If instead the line is meant to "*close*" or "*end*" the main content area, then you should probably go with solution2, in case there is no main content area.

You could instead also re-define our question – at least for yourself: Currently you're asking if you should keep the line that "*separates content from footer*". This means that the line, as you describe it, is meant to separate ***content*** from ***footer***. So the only thing you'll have to figure out is basically: *Is the 'features section' part of the content?* Then keep the line. Or *is 'features section' **not** part of the content?* Then don't keep the line.